# How to embed sfDoctrineGuard's login and take the user to another app's default route on successful login?

Tags: authentication, symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

Well, basically that: I've got apps A and B and I want 2 things:

1) Login form embedded in A's layout

2) Redirect to B's default route on successful login

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app.yml, you can set the sfGuard login default route for a successful login:

```
all:
  sf_guard_plugin:
    success_signin_url:      @somepage
    success_signout_url:     @someotherpage
```

One way would be to set the success_signin_url to point to an action whose only purpose is to re-direct the user to your other app, for example:

```
$this->redirect('http://www.mydomain.com/myotherapp/');  // I think absolute URL is fine here
```

There may be a way to make the routing rules of two apps talk to each, but not sure, perhaps by setting project-level routing rules in a new routing.yml.

Comment: I set up 2 routes for singin and singout and use them in app.yml like you said, all this in app A. I now need to make the form work in A's layout so I can actually test all this, but everywhere I see people recommends creating a separate app C to take care of inter-app security situations. I'm not going there, yet; embedding a form wherever you want MUST be doable, so if I have that, I can test these routes and then move on.

Comment: @leomdg: I think putting the form in your layout is a complete separate thing. Just instantiate the form object for the sfDoctrineGuard class in a component, stick the component in your layout, and make the form post normally to the standard sfDoctrineGuard action. You only need the component to render the form, not process the POST.

Comment: Thing is: the login form is part of the app's global layout.php, so I can't make a component for it; tried using app's /lib but that didn't work (I guess it's not like actions and templates).

Comment: How to enable app layout components? Tried several ways, couldn't do it nor found any specific documentation ):

Comment: Well, since I don't want to waste your time: I solved it in another way, using regular templates and partials and playing with routes. Your answer about app.yml route definition was very usefull and what really made the form redirect to where I wanted, so I'll give it the green check :) Cheers.

Comment: @leomdg: If you want to try the component method, just create the component somewhere else in your application. I personally like to have a "general" module for various small elements like this, and then just call them wherever I need to: <?php include_component('general', 'loginMenu'); ?> .... where "general" is the module name and "loginMenu" is the action/partial for the component. You can call this in a layout as well.

Comment: That's indeed a good idea since my problem was not beign able to call the component. Thanks for that!